# 'class' or 'interface' excepted android studio xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I don't see why I'm having this error, here's my Android Manifest.xml which is the code that is having the error

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapplication" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        <!--error at this line-->android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here's my HomeActivity class

```
   package com.myapplication;

   import android.app.ActionBar;

   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
   import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

   public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
//Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Generate lyrics", "Bookmarks", "Top 100" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    // Initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    //Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
}
```

The code above creates tabs pretty much, I'm pretty new to Android Studio, I just recently switched over from Eclipse

EDIT:
I've said before this is the error I'm getting
https://i.stack.imgur.com/slFom.png

Does this mean anything? I just found this
[image]

Still in need of help!

Comment: you have to specify the whole path. try this--> android:name="com.myapplication.HomeActivity"

Comment: @aradhna Not if you include a period as the first character: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm

Comment: The error message is the title I think

Comment: can you fix your imports? You have mixed import from the support library and the framework

Comment: can you post your error log?

Comment: @aradhna it is a compile time error

Comment: How would I fix this?

Comment: @Mitch - I can't see any issues with your manifest file syntactically. What does the error say. Any clue?

Comment: How would I find the error, because all i see is the error that i gave in the title

Comment: @Mitch - Point the mouse cursor to that error code. Does that give any clue ?

Comment: Look at the link I posted

Comment: @Mitch - You haven't posted `<uses-permission>` tag as I see in your image. Was that intentional ?

Comment: Yes, I just added that, in my Websites class I use the Internet to fetch lyrics of the song of their choice

Comment: @Mitch - Your project folders are not properly placed. As I see you have `com.myapplication` package inside the folder `src/main/java`. Try placing this package directly in the `src` folder. Then check.

Comment: Doesn't help at all sadly, if I move myapplication out of the java folder it shows its not a class anymore, if I move the java folder out of the main folder, nothing happens

Comment: @Mitch - Then let it remain as was before. Instead check your manifest is properly structured and includes all the tags required for the project like http://gurushya.com/android-manifest/.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving fully qualified name for `android:name`,

**android:name**

> The name of the class that implements the activity, a subclass of
>   Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name
>   (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity"). However, as
>   a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for
>   example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to the package
>   name specified in the  element. Once you publish your
>   application, you should not change this name (unless you've set
>   android:exported="false").
>
> There is no default. The name must be specified.

More at [Android Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Also consider to read the [7 things you should know about Android Manifest xml file](http://gurushya.com/android-manifest/).

Comment: I recommend that you auto generate a new android project and put your relevant java files there. This should work.

Comment: I've tried that about 10 times now, I'm just not sure what to do anymore

Comment: @Mitch - If its too much now and you still unable to resolve, then you can share the project with me and I will correct it and send you back.

Comment: I'd like that, how did you want me to send it? Email?

Comment: Ok Email that to me. My email address is mentioned in my profile.

Comment: No need, I deleted everything that Android Studio used(.Gradle, etc) then reinstalled it and that fixed it, now I'm just trying to fix an error that is saying Cannot Resolve R